# Escape html entities twig form widget

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to escape those double quotes in  post_data.postCaption1 as below. But it seems not working. How to do it?

```
<div class="form-group">
      {% autoescape %}
        {{ form_widget(blog_form.post_caption1, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter caption for image 1', 'value': post_data.postCaption1|raw } }) }} {% endautoescape %}
        {{ form_errors(blog_form.post_caption1) }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [raw filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html), **post_data.postCaption1** won't be escaped because *raw* is the last filter applied to it:

```
{% autoescape %}
    {{ var|raw }} {# var won't be escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

You can try:

```
{% set strategy = 'html' %}
{% autoescape %}
    {{ form_widget(blog_form.post_caption1, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter caption for image 1', 'value': post_data.postCaption1|escape(strategy) } }) }} 
{% endautoescape %}
{{ form_errors(blog_form.post_caption1) }}
```

Comment: No. It's adding &amp; instead.

Comment: Show your complete output please @ChandimalRox

Comment: &amp;quot;P.R.I.C.E&amp;quot;

Comment: @ChandimalRox what is the initial value inside post_data.postCaption1

Comment: Franck Gamess its ok I did it in controller